# Registration on django

Tags: json, django, registration

I am writing an API and have a problem with registration: `ValueError : The given username should be set`.

Here is the code:

```
def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        check_username = User.objects.filter(username__exact=username)
        check_email = User.objects.filter(email__exact=email)

        if check_email.count() != 0:
            if check_username.count() != 0:
               check = json.dumps('User with such name or email already registered. Please, rewrite your name or email.')
            return HttpResponse(check, content_type='application/json')

        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2', '')

        if password != password2:
            wrong_password_message = json.dumps('The passwords do not match. Please, rewrite!')
            return HttpResponse(wrong_password_message, content_type='application/json')
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.is_staff = False
            user.is_superuser = False
            user.save()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('Hello new User!'), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)`
```

as

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)`
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [paradoksumsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3416136/paradoksumsu) didn't help, although he said right from the point of view of the syntax of the function 'create_user'.

To fix this error you should do the following:

-change all `request.POST.get('smth')` to `request.META[HTTP_SMTH]`

as i.e.:

```
username = request.META['HTTP_USERNAME']
email = request.META['HTTP_EMAIL']
```

It works.